# How to stop ffmpeg from adding "handler_name" to metadata

Tags: ffmpeg

I run `ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -codec copy 2.mp4` to remove all the metadata. But ffmpeg add `handler_name : SoundHandler` to audio track and `handler_name : VideoHandler` to video track.

Is there a option to disable it?

I am running ffmpeg 3.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: No**w** possible. You can specify a custom value, including an empty string to remove it.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -codec copy -metadata:s handler_name=somestring 2.mp4
```

Comment: I have submitted a bug report to ffmpeg. I will something else for replacement now.

Comment: Where's the bug?

Comment: `handler_name` is not mandatory in mp4 metadata. If ffmpeg adds it automatically and cannot be disable, should not it be consider a bug?

Comment: Replied at the tracker.

Comment: @Gyan can you link to the tracker so the rest of us can see the discussion?

Comment: @DavidMoles https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7262

Comment: This didn't work for me in ffmpeg 4.2.2. I tried setting `handler_name` to an empty string, but it still wrote `handler_name : SoundHandler`. My command was: `ffmpeg -i input.m4a -c copy -metadata:s:a:0 handler_name='' output.m4a`. I also tried with no string `handler_name=`, same result. Only a space worked `handler_name=' '`

Comment: You have to tell ffmpeg that an empty string is ok. Add `-empty_hdlr_name 1`

Comment: Wow, `-empty_hdlr_name 1` worked, thanks! The complete command is `ffmpeg -i input.m4a -c copy -metadata:s:a:0 handler_name='' -empty_hdlr_name 1 output.m4a`